# Form inheritance should be abstract

Tags: forms, inheritance, overriding, abstract

Here my code

**GeneralLesson.cs**: it's just a .cs file, no .Designer.cs or .resx file

```
public /*abstract*/ class GeneralLesson : Form
{
    public GeneralLesson()
    {
        this.StartPosition = SS.FrmStartPos;//If I want to change it later, I just change it here and all the children will get the change
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

        SS.LearningDay = 0; //SS is my static class that hold the static variables.
        SS.FrmMain.Show();
    }
}
```

**SentLesson.cs**: This is actually a windows form, with .Designer.cs and .resx file

```
public partial class _Sent_Lesson : GeneralLesson
{
    public _Sent_Lesson()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        richTextBox1.Text = "under construction";
    }

}
```

So it actually serves my purpose well. my SentLesson window inherits the constructor and OnFormClosing from GeneralLesson. But the problem is I can't design my SentLesson window any more, it shows as the picture below:
[image: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Maybe I do it wrong. But I don't want to create GeneralLesson as a Window because I don't design any control on it, I just want to override some function like OnFormClosing or the Constructor. Is there any way I can do this without making GeneralLesson as a Window.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: what is `SS`? What are the details of the thrown exception? Your question title says "should be abstract" but I don't see any `abstract` types in your question. Note that `abstract` types cannot be used with the WinForms designer.

Comment: @Dai SS is my static class that hold the static variables. I comment it in my code.
At the beginning, I create the General Lesson as "public abstract class GeneralLesson : Form" but later I changed it to "public class GeneralLesson : Form" - Same thing anyway, still get the Error page. and the throw exception is not from my code, it causes because Visual Studio can not load the Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution. Even though the abstract parent form still works logically, but the children form can't be designed any further with Visual Studio designer. So I have to inherit forms the Visual Studio way.
[image]

As you can see, Visual Studio provides us Inherited Form to create Children form. So I create GeneralLesson.cs as Windows Form, and SentLesson.cs as Inherited Form. So SentLesson inherits constructor and OnFormClosing from GeneralLesson and the designer of SentLesson no longer shows error.

If you want the Children form can access some controls from the Parent form, say Parent's "Button A". Just set the Parent's "Button A" 's Modifiers in properties window from Private to Protected. Then you can do anything with Button A in the Children form.

Thank for your reading.